# Is there any way to mix spring-security java configuration and @secured annotation?

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-security, spring-annotations

I setting up spring security to web app. I want to make global security rules (permit all authenticated users on GET and permit only with role ADMIN on other http methods) and add custom rules to endpoints with `@Secured` annotation.

When i do config and `@Secured` annotation like that user with only role SUPER_USER cant access that endpoint

```
override def configure(http: HttpSecurity): Unit = {
    http
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, ALL)
      .permitAll()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(ALL).hasRole("ADMIN")
  }
```

```
@DeleteMapping(value = Array("/{id}"))
@Secured(Array("SUPER_USER"))
def delete(@PathVariable("id") id: String): Unit = {...}
```

I expect to have global security rules and custom rules with `@Secured`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: They are complementary. So now the user has to have both `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_SUPER_USER` in his list of authorities. If one of them is missing, he will not have access. If that isn't working add the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation to your security config. Another option would be to use a role hierarchy meaning that `SUPER_USER` would extend `ADMIN`.

Comment: Is there any option to check if user has ROLE_ADMIN form java config or ROLE_SUPER_USER form Secured annotation?

Comment: No. As mentioned they are complementary. The security filter first checks the rules defined in the config, then an additional aspect check the `@Secured` / `@PreAuthorize` checks.

Comment: Just to re-enforce the comment from @M.Deinum , you can check on [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [@PreAuthorize](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security). It will solve your problem.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('" + <Your Role> + "')")
```

Comment: It's not work. It's look like request match .antMatchers(ALL).hasRole("ADMIN"), check that user has not role admin, return AccessDenied and not check if he has role SUPER_USER form annotation \@Secured or \@PreAuthorize

Comment: If `@Secured` doesn't work neither will `@PreAuthorize`.